# Convert format of DateTime column in wpf Datagrid

Tags: wpf, date, datetime, datagrid

i have a datagrid like this.

[image]

I want to convert the Date column format so as to show 5/11/2014 as 11th May 2014 and also i dont want to display time. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Three options:

1. Use a ContentTemplate and format the column's value on binding.
2. Handle the OnBinding event and modify the value being set.
3. Just after values or loaded or (if you are using a sproc to fetch data), send the data to the MT or UI after having already formatted it.

Comment: Can you give me a small example please